# get TimeStamp common readable google sheets script

Tags: javascript, date, google-sheets

My sheet contains a column with a timestamp and my variable 'value' delivers:
Fri Mar 17 11:35:12 GMT+01:00 2023
This is correct, but I would like to 'transform' the value in a common 'german format'.
I have done this:

```js
var germanValue = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(value), "GMT+1", "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm")
```

I get:
17.03.2023 11:35
But how to display also the day-name something like,
Freitag, 17.03.2023 11:35 (where Freitag ist friday in german language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
var germanValue = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(value), "GMT+1", "EEEE, dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
console.log(germanValue);
```

Or:

```
var germanDate = new Date(value).toLocaleDateString('de-DE', {weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric'});
var germanTime = new Date(value).toLocaleTimeString('de-DE');
console.log(germanDate+" "+germanTime);
```

#### Reference:

- [Class SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)
- [toLocaleTimeString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString)
- [toLocaleDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

Comment: This works perfectly. The first option gives me weekdays in English, the second option weekdays translated in German. Great, thank you!